# Azure DevOps YAML hide tasks assistant

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How can I hide this task assistant by default. It is very annoying and I never use it.
[image]

Comment: Hi Blue,Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. Do you have any other concern?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not support right now. I have created a feature request for you in our user voice site.

> **Allow a setting to hide tasks assistant in YAML pipeline by default**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1156607/allow-a-setting-to-hide-tasks-assistant-in-yaml-pi.html

You could kindly vote up it and monitor status. Our PM will also review it.

At present, you have to manually click the Hide assistant button as a workaround.

[image]